# Why does this for loop not run? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/BvuT5/

Trying to get the 2nd alert to popup twice, however seems like the for loop isn't even running.

jQuery

```
var wireRequestorCard = function(jarjar) {

    alert('1st alert');

    var loop_num = 0;
    for (var i = 0, length = jarjar.length; i < length; i++) {
        loop_num = i;
        alert('Where is this Alert? '+i);
        }

    alert('Closing Alert');
    }

var jarjar = 2;

wireRequestorCard(jarjar);
```

Comment: To fix you should be able to change length = jarjar.length; i < length to just i < jarjar

Comment: Why was I downvoted? I had a problem, albeit one that was easily fixed, however a valid issue otherwise. I was trying to replicate an issue in my actual project. I have an object in there instead of just a number. However failed to copy more code over into jsFiddle. This however is still a valid question.

Comment: @Leon Maybe you did not think to look in the js console and see the error?

Comment: @Neal no error in the console, neither is there an error in my project where I'm using an object. Will probably end up with a new question later with much more code displayed.

Comment: People downvote for no reason Leon, I also find this very annoying. This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/BvuT5/5/ solves your problem?

Comment: @Neal his code doesn't produce any errors, although I agree a simple `console.log( jarjar.length );` would say its undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/BvuT5/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't passing an array or string to the function, which does not have a `length` property. Instead `jarjar` is a number.

Answer (score 5):

`jarjar` is an integer.

it does **not** have a `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compare `i` to `jarjar`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jarjar; i++) {
    alert('Here is this Alert! '+i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/BvuT5/5/